# Displaying rows of images on 100% width

Tags: html, css

I need to display images in my grid with the following idea: every `li` elements of each `ul`tag should stay in the same row and be 100% width of the container.

As you can see in the jsfiddle, for the demo, I created 3 `ul`. So I would like 3 rows of images.

The jsfiddle: [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1wan240/1/)

The final result should be like below:

[image]

I don't know how to proceed so that every row takes 100% width.

So every row (`ul`) may contains 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 images.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every li elements of each ultag should stay in the same row and be 100% width of the container

You needs to use Flexbox

---

### Result

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li+li {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=A1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200?text=A2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200?text=A3">
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=B1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=B2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200?text=B3">
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="fivePerRow">
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=C1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200?text=C2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200?text=C3">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=C4">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=C5">
  </li>
</ul>
```

And same code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohrnLvp9/)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think using Flexbox will do the job.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/syed_n_sakib/pen/BaBvzZm)

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the width of each images is not adjusted to fill space. So there is extra blank space between each images (of the same row).

Comment: Apply 'flex-grow' property on each image (or the image you want) according to your need.